# using Flutter/dart, what's a better way to display a dot for everyday of the year which color of the dots can be changed depending on data

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter/dart and have currently made this, but on the backend it looks like a mess. I figured there has to be a better way to do it.
I also was wondering what would the best way to change the color or each dot specifically.
just looking for some general advice and perhaps an article or two to read or a yt vid.
Thank you.[pic of front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls1Wz.png)

right now im using a gridview but with 365/366 dots, one for each day, the code looks a bit messy and im not sure how i would change each dot independently. for example if i had an array 365 long full of bool's an each day corresponded to a dot. green if true, grey of false. how would i efficiently code that?
Thanks again[pic of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ExIT.png)

heres a small snippet of the code

```
                      Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      childAspectRatio: (1.4 / 1),
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
                      crossAxisCount: 13,
                      children: [
                        const Center(child: Text('')),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('J',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('F',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('M',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('A',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('M',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('J',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('J',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('A',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('S',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('O',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('N',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('D',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('1',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('2',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('3',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('4',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('5',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('6',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('7',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Center(
                            child: Text('8',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: AppColors.textColLightGrey))),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.circle,
                          color: AppColors.pixelNotDone,
                          size: 15,
                        ),
```

Comment: Note on your "_just looking for some \[...\] article or two to read or a yt vid_". Can you please read #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic)) and then consider removing that recommendation request)?

Comment: Upon actually reading your question, this sounds more like a [codereview.se] question. I suggest you read [The guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/267244) to see if your question fits there instead. See also [their on-topic help page](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [their ask-checklist FAQ](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1954/267244).

Comment: The part of your question about how to change each dot indepdendently- if that's not implemented yet- ask that here on Stack Overflow- not on codereview.stackexchange.com, but the part asking for code review on the parts that are _already implemented and working as intended_, that part probably fits better there instead of here.

Comment: Share your entire gridView widget code with data for better understanding.

Comment: okay, its a lot @VishalZaveri editing now

Comment: Sorry i couldnt pate it all in as its too long, so im very sure im doing this in an really inefficient way just not sure how else to do it with my current understanding of flutter